# Make suggested edits which indent code easier to verify

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, code-formatting, diff

It's fairly frequent to review suggested edits where someone helpfully puts code into code blocks.  For instance:

[image: Suggested edit to code]

These edits are great and are appreciated; they generally improve the atmosphere of the site and improve the quality and readability of the post in specific.  Also, most of the time, there's no problem reviewing these edits.  However, it has occurred to me that an unscrupulous user could edit errors or even spam into the code block and have it passed unnoticed.

Obviously, this isn't an issue in most cases, but since new and even unregistered users can propose edits, there could be edits that have been approved which never should have been.

I've thought of two possible solutions:

#### 1. Don't diff the code; just diff the spaces

In other words, don't turn the entire code (in picture above, on the left) red; just put a red strip down the left side.  On the left side, just put a green strip on the right side.  A normal diff should be run between the actual *texts*.

#### 2. Have the system autotest the code when indents are suggested and warn if the code fails to line up.

---

Generally, I prefer the first system; it seems easier to implement (though I could be wrong).  It also seems that it would be easier to see differences between the two code blocks, since you would have a clear red on the left and green on the right in the event of a difference.

Comment: that edit isn't putting anything into a code block, it's *blockquoting* the text.  Doesn't necessarily invalidate your request, but doesn't do anything to help it either. Also, that edit should probably be rejected, since it mangles the log.

Comment: Actually, I *think* it does both; it's a faulty edit, I believe; one with 4 spaces and a >.

Comment: But good point, I'll try to find a better illustration.

Comment: You know there are different views when looking at a suggested edit? You want to see the side-by-side markdown view, which does accurately reflect spacing changes.

Comment: Good point @animuson; I assumed anonymous2 was already using that; if not, then this probably *is* a blockquote in a code block, which just makes this even more of an insanely-bad edit *even if it doesn't change the text at all*.

Comment: Hmm, good point, @animuson. That does fix the issue, thanks!

Comment: @Shog9, true that.

Comment: You should make a habit of *always* checking the side-by-side markdown view when reviewing edits in general, for this reason and others, especially if the edit is borderline sketchy, as every once in a while somebody does like to do something dumb like put a snarky remark in an HTML comment or something.